# Generating a custom version of Dygraphs

Tags: npm, dygraphs

I need to create a custom version of Dygraph which I will be installing directly from my fork's Github repo (using npm). My question is:
How do I generate the files that are generated by a regular Dygraphs npm install? Such as dygraphs-combined-dev? I don't see them generated by npm run build.

Hope i'm being clear... 
Thanks,
Uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my answer is largely speculative from reading the commit history in the GitHub repository.

The latest stable release (1.1.1) was in June 2015, but the build process was overhauled in October 2015. It seems likely that `dygraph-combined-dev.js` and `dygraph-combined.js` will be renamed in the next stable release to `dygraph.js` and `dygraph.min.js`.

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/DEVELOP.md), by calling `npm run build` you will generate these files in to the `dist` folder.

If you need compatibility with the previous names, you may need to modify `scripts/build.sh` to rename these files appropriately.